# Pine script how to feed array data from Tradview into pine script value

Tags: pine-script

I want to sum up all x values in Tradeview into a function
x = array.sum(x)

Where the array of x values sums up and the answer on the left is one integer. How do i tell pine script to get the x values on the chart and feed into sum(x). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
sum_x = cum(bar_index)
```

or

```
var int[] x_vals = array.new_int()

array.unshift(x_vals, bar_index)
sum_x = array.sum(x_vals)
```